# Return value, with an if statement in a for loop

Tags: java, if-statement, foreach

My method is supposed to return a Card, I have an if statement within a for loop - I don't want to add 'return c' at the end, as that will return the last Card in carddeck. I'm getting errors saying "must return type Card". What would you advise?

P.S. this is one of my first posts - apologies if it has an obvious answer. All these brackets are putting me off...

```
  public Card findRightCardWithIndex(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    for(Card c:carddeck) {
      if (c.getIndex() == index) {
        return c;
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `else`. Move the `throw` outside the `for` statement. Otherwise, what would the method return if `carddeck` was empty?

Comment: `'return c' at the end, as that will return the last Card in carddeck` it will lead to another compile error as `c` is defined only inside of for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct way of doing it.

```
public Card findRightCardWithIndex(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  Card card;
  for(Card c:carddeck) {
    if (c.getIndex() == index) {
      card =  c;
      break;
    }
    if(card != null){ // you shuld make an empty method here
      return card;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No card found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is scan the entire list and if you can't find it, then generate a response when you can't find it..

```
 public Card findRightCardWithIndex(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    for(Card c:carddeck) {
      if (c.getIndex() == index) {
         return c;
      }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change this code to Java 8 Streams, that makes it more obvious and less error-prone (but slightly slower).

Example:

```
public Card findRightCardWithIndex(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return cards.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getIndex() == index)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a null Card object, if you find the index inside the loop then assign the card to your object and terminate the loop with break.
If your object is not null then return the object, else you throw an exception because it means there was no card with that index.

```
public Card findRightCardWithIndex(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Card card = null;
    for (Card c : carddeck) {
        if (c.getIndex() == index) {
            card = c;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (card != null) {
        return card;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index");
    }
}
```